# Load primeng tree in a scrollable window

Tags: angular, primeng

How can I load the tree control in a scrollable window? I want this window to open
when i click the arrow icon and a label to show the selected items - like the multiselect control (https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/multiselect) ?

Comment: Didn't completely get what you are asking. Can you elaborate? Just setting `overflow: auto` will make any container scrollable.

Comment: I want the tree control to be like the multiselect control but instead of collection of selected items to show the elements of the tree when I expand to see the available options.